# SQL Query showing gateway timeout

Tags: php, mysql

I have a complaint management system. It can be accessed after logging with the credentials.The landing page shows the full list of registered complaints which has about 5000 rows.

The page is getting slower and slower. Usually it shows Gateway timeout. Below is the query used to populate the list. To reduce the page loading time I have reduced the row to from id 4500. Is there any better way so that the page loads faster?

```
$qry="SELECT a.*, b.statusType, b.statusNote
      FROM call_log a
      LEFT JOIN `complaint_status` b ON a.id = b.call_log_id
      WHERE a.userId=".$_SESSION['userId'] ."
      AND a.status=1 AND a.id>4500 ". $condition;
```

Comment: Did you try to create index on your columns?

Comment: Or create a view that does the heavy work on the DB

Comment: can u please explain how to do this as am a newbie to php and mysql

Comment: This looks terrifyingly insecure. Are you **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php)? Where does `$condition` come from and what might it contain?

Comment: It is used for filter option

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are missing some indexes. 5k rows should not be a problem.
Check if you have indexes setup with 
    DESC
, and if not, add them with 
    ALTER TABLE `table_name` ADD INDEX(`column_name`)

More info here :
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb/1.1/en/innodb-create-index-examples.html